# Change Day format to Sun Mon

Tags: solspace-calendar

I am using Solspace Calendar. I would like to change the date format from Sunday, Monday to Sun, Mon  Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

You can format the names with standard EE date formatting. try {day format="%j"}, as documented in the [ExpressionEngine User Guide](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/templates/date_variable_formatting.html).

Comment: @user2121, in the future, I recommend referencing the Date Formatting Codes section on this nifty cheat sheet: http://ellislab.com/_user_guide_src_ee/_images/ee_quick_reference.png

Comment: Can you please guid me where exactly I can try this? I have tried to use it as following {exp:calendar:month day_format="%j%"} but it is not working.

Comment: The syntax is incorrect. 1st, it's **%j**, not %j%. 2nd, there is no day_format="" param for {exp:calendar:month}. Next, if you're looking to format each event's date (eg the start date), use {event_start_date format="%j"} within your {exp:calendar:month}. If you need to change the names of the weekdays in your calendar table's header (eg. S M T W T F S), you'll need to use the more flexible {exp:calendar:cal} with the variable options available within that tag pair. Please see the docs and advanced example in [the Solspace documentation](http://www.solspace.com/docs/calendar/month//#examples)